# How to use imshow in matplotlib to display image in a for loop and save each image in one file?

Tags: loops, for-loop, imshow

I want to use imshow in matplotlib to show each data, and save each into one file. My code is as following:

```
X = mnist['data']
for i in range(10):
    print(X[i])
    plt.imshow(X[i].reshape(28, 28), cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'), vmin=0, vmax=255)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.axis('square')
    plt.savefig('./' + str(i) + '.png', format='png', dpi=300)
    #plt.show()
```

However, the first image is always blank, while all others are saved correctly. I tried various methods, including adding `plt.show()`, which will not save any image correctly (all become blank); or adding `plt.pause(0.05)`, using `figure()` or something else, but no one works.

I can use `plt.imshow` and `savefig` correctly without loop, like save several different images.

Comment: Is there potential for X[0] to be empty and so nothing is plotted? The loop seems correct to me.

Comment: Thanks Matt. If I plot them without loop, the output will be correct and X[0] is not empty. @MattB

Comment: What results do you get if you reverse the loop? does x[0] then show and x[10] not show?